# Curl not working with Zen Cart

Tags: php, http, curl, http-headers, zen-cart

I am trying to post data to a zen cart page, but curl doesnt work.  It doesnt matter what I try to do, even if it's just trying to obtain the headers, I get 404 errors or I get 302 errors (depending on the page and what I'm trying to do).  Ultimately, I need to be able to log in as a user and complete a transaction from the command line but that seems impossible given the 302 errors.

For example, this is what I type to obtain the headers:

```
curl -I -3 www.splitsum.com/zcart/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=0&products_id=1
```

And this is the return:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2013 20:52:59 GMT
Server: Apache
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?  I installed a different shopping cart on the same server and can access it and complete transactions via curl without a problem, but I am not having the same luck with Zen Cart.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: if its your own cart, then there are better approaches than this

Comment: @Dagon No, unfortunately it is not for my own cart.

Comment: then this kind of activity is rarely desired by site owners.

Comment: What about using something like Mechanize or Snoopy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zen-cart has prevention from robots you can try to send different headers basically when you change User-Agent it should work

this worked for me copying from my own browser :

curl --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" -I -3 "www.splitsum.com/zcart/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=0&products_id=1"